# Conflict btwn PanGesture and TapGesture

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

My app consists of a deck of cards. Most cards in the deck are made in draggableView. I'm trying to make it so that a double tap on the screen will make my buttons on the card disappear/reappear. After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811154/xcode-how-to-hide-buttons), I tried to give it shot. I put a UITapGesture into my initWithFrame method in my draggableView class, like so:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    [self addSubviewFromNib];
    [self setupView];
    panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(beingDragged:)];
    cardWidth = frame.size.width;
    cardHeight = frame.size.height;
    type = 0;
    panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    _backgroundScrollView.panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    //...more code above....
    _backgroundScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]   initWithTarget:_backgroundScrollView action:@selector(doubleTap)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = _backgroundScrollView;
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[_backgroundScrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

}

 - (void) doubleTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesturerecognizer{

    _mapButton.hidden = !_mapButton.hidden;
    _menuButton.hidden = !_menuButton.hidden;
    _phoneButton.hidden = !_phoneButton.hidden;
    reviewButton.hidden = !reviewButton.hidden;
    _shareButton.hidden = !_shareButton.hidden;

}


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    // If the gesture recognizer is a UITapGestureRecongizer, but the other
    // gesture detected is a UIPanGestureRecognizer, require the
    // UITapGestureRecognizer to fail.
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] &&
        [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}



- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return YES;
    }
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
        CGPoint velocity = [panGesture velocityInView:self];
        return fabs(velocity.y) <= fabs(velocity.x);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

However, if I double tap, I get this sib abrt error:

```
 -[UITapGestureRecognizer velocityInView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9f9a244230
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer velocityInView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9f9a244230'
```

I'm assuming this means there's an error between the PanGestureRecognizer and the TapGesture Recognizer. How do I resolve it?

EDIT: Still unresolved, but if I change the tapGesture to be added to draggable view(thus, self), rather than _backgroundScrollView, I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DraggableView doubleTap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fefdd9e4f70'
```

OTHER EDIT: I changed it back to backgroundScrollView, and I now get this as the error:

```
[UIScrollView doubleTap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe5130af000
```

Comment: post the code related to pan gesture too. Also please post the correct code, you are missing a closing brace in the posted code.

Comment: Updated it with more code

Comment: gestureRecognizerShouldBegin will get called, whenver the gesture recogniser is about to procss the touches, it could  be either tap gesture or it could be either pan gesture. YOu need to check the gestureRecogniser type and then proceed further,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare the types of gestures on iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475250/how-to-compare-the-types-of-gestures-on-ios)

Comment: I tried the solution offered in that thread, but still got the same sig abrt error :/

Comment: You need to change the gestureRecognizerShouldBegin as suggested in that answer.

Comment: So, I implemented gestureRecognizerShouldBegin as: - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] &&
        [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
} still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error: 
in my h file, I needed to use draggableView as the delegate for tapGesture and then insert gestureRecognizer into UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol, like so:

```
@protocol UIGestureRecognizerDelegate <NSObject>
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

`gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` will get called, whenver the gesture recogniser is about to procss the touches, it could be either tap gesture or it could be either pan gesture. YOu need to check the gestureRecogniser type and then proceed further.

Implement the following method(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475250/how-to-compare-the-types-of-gestures-on-ios)) to allow simultaneous gestures to be recognised:

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    // If the gesture recognizer is a UITapGestureRecongizer, but the other
    // gesture detected is a UIPanGestureRecognizer, require the
    // UIPanGestureRecognizer to fail.
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] &&
        [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])  {
       return YES;
    } else {
       return NO;
    }
}
```

and in the other delegate method, the crash reason tells you that:

```
-[UITapGestureRecognizer velocityInView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9f9a2
```

`velocityInView` is being called on wrong gesture type, to avoid these kind of errors, modify your delegate method as below:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
  if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {     
       return YES;
  }
  if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) { 
       UIPanGestureRecogniser *panGesture = (UIPanGestureRecongiser *)gestureRecogniser;    
       CGPoint velocity = [panGesture velocityInView:self];
       return fabs(velocity.y) <= fabs(velocity.x);
  }
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: i implemented gestureRecognizer:(changing UILongPressGestureRecognizer to UIPanGestureRecognizer) and gestureRecognizerShouldBegin, but still get the same error :/

Comment: did u change the gestureRecognizerShouldBegin as per my answer ?

Comment: Yeah, I changed that to what you gave above -- still same error

Comment: okay, please update your question with what you tried just now, and we will see what is wrong.

Comment: I updated the gestureRecognizerShouldBegin method. Please try it. @MaddieElizabeth

Comment: Now I'm getting the error, "[UIScrollView doubleTap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" -- any suggestions? If UIScrollView is the delegate for tapGesture, shouldn't it be able to handle doubleTap?

Comment: change action:@selector(doubleTap) to action:@selector(doubleTap:). ALso make sure you are not calling doubleTap on scrollView instance.

Comment: Where is it possible that I'm calling doubleTap on a scrollview instance? I want to change that but I'm so new, I'm lost as to where that could be happening/where I should look. I don't see doubleTap being directly called anywhere in the code.

Comment: search for the doubleTap in your class. And find out if there is another occurence other than the initWithFrame method.

Comment: There's not, just the one occurance in initWithFrame